# endsWith() method always returns false

Tags: java, regex

I am on sketchware, an android app to create apps. Everything is made in blocks, but compiled in pure normal regular java.

I can't seem to find the problem, but the `endsWith` method always returns `false`. Even when it ends with 0, 6 or whatever.

```
if (!textview1.getText().toString().isEmpty() == true) {
    // the expression in the following if statement never evaluates to true
    if (textview1.toString().endsWith("[10-9]") == true) {
        symbols.add("-");
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText().toString().concat("-"));
    } else {
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "false");
    }
} else {
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Can't use symbols before numbers");
}
```

Comment: `endsWith()`'s suffix is not a regex. It's just a substring.

Comment: Oh... how can I check for multiple suffixes?

Comment: Guys, there will be people that make the same mistake. `String` methods sometimes take reg exp strings and sometimes not, after all. So either find a dupe or allow this question, because it seems perfectly valid to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-

The parameter inside `endsWith` should be a character sequence. Your string must not have the character sequence, `[0-9]` at the end of it and therefore you are always getting `false` as the result.

You should write it as follows:

```
if(textview1.toString().matches("^.*\\d$"))
```

**Note**: This will return `true` if you have a number at the end of the string. If you want it to return `true` if there is a number anywhere inside the string, you should use `matches(".*\\d.*")`.

Comment: Thank you! I just want to check for any number in the method. How can I do that. Check if a string ends with a number.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) `endsWith` method

> Tests if this string ends with the specified suffix.

So, if you pass for instance `test1` as a string, `endsWith` will evaluate false because `test1` doesn't end with `[0-9]`.

You need to use regex for that. Use `matches` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) from the `String` class.

Example:

```
 String test = "test2";
 System.out.println(test.endsWith("[0-9]")); //false
 System.out.println(test.matches(".*[0-9]$")); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regex expression is probably going to be your best bet in getting this to work correctly. Something similar to this:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]$").matcher(textView1.toString()).find())
```

This should end up returning true or false based on if the last character in the string matches 0-9.

Comment: I'm a proponent of `find` although I think using `Pattern` and `Matcher` is a bit much for this simple task. However to extract the number I'd use `find` with `"\\d+$"` to find the number string at then end (or not).